# Exception while trying to repair mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I just migrated my Meteor App from 1.2 to 1.8.
Now I am trying to repair mongodb so that It can be compatible with new mongodb version.

I am using this command to repair my mongodb:

```
~/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.8.0_1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/mongodb/bin/mongod --dbpath /my-app/.meteor/local/db --repair
```

But I am getting this exception when I run this command:

```
Exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /my-app/.meteor/local/db not found., terminating
```

Meteor Server is running on port 3000
Mongodb is running on port 3001

Comment: Do you try to o repair your local mongo DB that is shipped with meteor or some mongo installation on your OS?

Comment: Local mongodb of meteor

Answer (score 0):

This topic might help: https://forums.meteor.com/t/mongo-4-meteor-1-8/46065

Answer in particular: https://forums.meteor.com/t/mongo-4-meteor-1-8/46065/8

Or if you did a backup before upgrade it's easier.
Reset and Restore, in that case should do the trick.